# Check for a key pattern in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, string-matching

```
    dict1=({"EMP$$1":1,"EMP$$2":2,"EMP$$3":3})
```

How to check if EMP exists in the dictionary using python

```
   dict1.get("EMP##") ??
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Can you rephrase your question? Providing sample inputs and output would help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want to do.

You can loop through the keys in the `dict` selecting keys using [the `startswith()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
>>> for key in dict1:
...     if key.startswith("EMP$$"):
...         print "Found",key
...
Found EMP$$1
Found EMP$$2
Found EMP$$3
```

You can use a list comprehension to get all the values that match:

```
>>> [value for key,value in dict1.items() if key.startswith("EMP$$")]
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you just want to know if a key matches you could use [the `any()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> any(key.startswith("EMP$$") for key in dict1)
True
```

Comment: I had tried this as in your first example and i put an else after it,the if part condition seems to be wrong....

Comment: I tried this approach and it works as the author intended.  Adding an else works for me as well.  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 8):

This approach strikes me as contrary to the intent of a dictionary.

A dictionary is made up of hash keys which have had values associated with them.  The benefit of this structure is that it provides very fast lookups (on the order of O(1)).  By searching through the keys, you're negating that benefit.

I would suggest reorganizing your dictionary.

```
dict1 = {"EMP$$": {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3} }
```

Then, finding "EMP$$" is as simple as

```
if "EMP$$" in dict1:
    #etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a lot more specific with what you want to do. However, assuming the dictionary you gave:

```
 dict1={"EMP$$1":1, "EMP$$2":2, "EMP$$3":3}
```

If you wanted to know if a specific key was present before trying to request it you could:

```
dict1.has_key('EMP$$1') 
True
```

Returns `True` as `dict1` has the a key `EMP$$1`.

You could also forget about checking for keys and rely on the default return value of `dict1.get()`:

```
dict1.get('EMP$$5',0)
0
```

Returns `0` as default given `dict1` doesn't have a key `EMP$$5`.

In a similar way you could also use a `try/except/ structure to catch and handle missed keys:

```
try:
    dict1['EMP$$5']
except KeyError, e:
    # Code to deal w key error
    print 'Trapped key error in dict1 looking for %s' % e
```

The other answers to this question are also great, but we need more info to be more precise.

Comment: SilentGhost is correct.  Use the form 'key in dict' rather than dict.has_key(key).  http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to match dictionary keys like this. I suggest you rethink your data structure for this problem. If this has to be extra quick you could use something like a suffix tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` string operator that checks if item is in another string. dict1 iterator returns list of keys, so you check "EMP$$" against of each dict1.key.

```
dict1 = {"EMP$$1": 1, "EMP$$2": 2, "EMP$$3": 3}

print(any("EMP$$" in i for i in dict1))
# True

# testing for item that doesn't exist
print(any("AMP$$" in i for i in dict1))
# False
```